# Code within same package not recognized

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 with Java SE.

I'm working on a project called Autocorrect with code in 2 folders, src and tests. In order to access private fields and methods, I'm trying to put my test files in the same package as my source files:

```
edu.brown.cs32.dtadams.<package>
```

Example:

```
package edu.brown.cs32.dtadams.trie; 

import org.junit.After; 
import org.junit.Before; 
import org.junit.Test; 
import static org.junit.Assert.*; 
import java.util.List; 

/* A generic class for testing methods in the "edu.brown.cs32.dtadams.trie" package 
 * 
 * @author Dominic Adams 
 * @version 1.0 2/13/13 
 */ 
public class TrieTest { 

...[TESTS]... 
}
```

I've been told that even though TrieTest is in a different root folder than the rest of the package it's in, NetBeans should recognize it as being in the same one. However, TrieTest doesn't seem to recognize any of the files from its own package. When I added

```
"import edu.brown.cs32.dtadams.SQTrie"
```

to the imports, I got back these two errors:

```
- cannot find symbol: ...[info]... 

- Import From The Same Package
```

So TrieTest recognizes that it's in a package of the same name as SQTrie, but NetBeans doesn't equate the two packages.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might cause this problem? Or any more information on how NetBeans handles packages across multiple folders?

Comment: _"In order to access private fields and methods"_ private fields and methods can **only** be accessed within the same class. Did you mean "protected?" There's no picture attached, BTW.

Comment: You use two different packages in your example (`edu.brown.cs32.dtadams` and `edu.brown.cs32.dtadams.trie`). Also, you appear to be asking at least two different questions. Are you asking how to access private variables between classes in the same package? Or are you asking why your imports cannot be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

To restrict method access to the same package use the [package private access modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
, which means put **nothing** in front of your method (no private/public/protected). Private is much stronger and restricts usage to the class itself.
This access modifier is also often used for unit tests to avoid over exposing the tested methods.